# xfinium: How To generate PDF with differant orientations

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, pdf

I try to create a PdfFlowDocument with header and footer. The page from 1 to 3 in Portrait mode. Page 4 is in Landscape and the rest again in portrait. Following my code code snippet:

```
        PdfFlowDocument flowDocument = new PdfFlowDocument();
        //flowDocument.HeadersFooters.EvenPagesHeader = docHeader;
        //flowDocument.HeadersFooters.EvenPagesFooter = docFooter;
        Xfinium.Pdf.Core.PdfFile sourceFile = new Core.PdfFile(File.OpenRead(""));
        Xfinium.Pdf.Graphics.PdfPageContent[] pageContents = sourceFile.ExtractPageContent(0, sourceFile.PageCount - 1);

        foreach (Xfinium.Pdf.Graphics.PdfPageContent content in pageContents)
        {
            //content can be Portrait or Landscape
            //How can I rotate the orientation?
            //How can I scale the page?
            var flowContent = new Xfinium.Pdf.FlowDocument.PdfFlowFormXObjectContent(content);
            flowDocument.AddContent(flowContent);
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You handle the PageCreated event and set the page rotation to 90 for landscape based on your specific condition.

```
PdfFlowDocument flowDocument = new PdfFlowDocument();
flowDocument.PageCreated += FlowDocument_PageCreated;

//flowDocument.HeadersFooters.EvenPagesHeader = docHeader;
//flowDocument.HeadersFooters.EvenPagesFooter = docFooter;
Xfinium.Pdf.Core.PdfFile sourceFile = new Core.PdfFile(File.OpenRead(""));
Xfinium.Pdf.Graphics.PdfPageContent[] pageContents = sourceFile.ExtractPageContent(0, sourceFile.PageCount - 1);

foreach (Xfinium.Pdf.Graphics.PdfPageContent content in pageContents)
{
    //content can be Portrait or Landscape
    //How can I rotate the orientation?
    //How can I scale the page?
    var flowContent = new Xfinium.Pdf.FlowDocument.PdfFlowFormXObjectContent(content);
    flowContent.SizeIsRelativeToAvailableSpace = true;
    flowContent.FormXObjectHeight = 100;
    flowContent.FormXObjectWidth = 100;

    flowDocument.AddContent(flowContent);
}

private void FlowDocument_PageCreated(object sender, PdfFlowPageCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (yourConditionHere)
    {
        e.Page.Rotation = 90;
    }
}
```

**Update**: you can set the `flowContent.SizeIsRelativeToAvailableSpace` property to true and `flowContent.FormXObjectWidth` and `flowContent.FormXObjectHeight` properties to 100. This means the content object will be scaled to take all available space (100%). It will also take care of the white page problem.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops the [XFINIUM.PDF](https://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-crossplatform/xfinium-pdf-features.html) library.

Comment: Thanks, that's worked. :-) But now I have the next Problem: -each PDF starts with an empty page. And how can I scale the content?

Comment: Please contact our support team, they will help you further.